# Copy latest files from SAP Server using Azure Data Factory and File System Linked Service and store it in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-file-copy

I have a task to copy the newly added files everyday from SAP Server and store it in ADLS. There are 2 types files on the server (Recurring and Upfront) appended with date. I need to store the files in separate folder and everyday add the latest file from the SAP Server to the ADLS.

File name format:
R_07292021.orc
Recurring_08312021.orc
U_07292021.orc
Upfront_08312021.orc

Below are the steps I have taken so far

1. Get Metadata Activity to get the list of files from the server
   [image]
2. Use filter activity to separate the files based on the names, so filtering with the initial letter
   [image]
3. I tried using the Foreach activity and If Condition, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am stuck at this point trying to figure out how to proceed. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what you are trying to do in foreach loop and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the latest modified date of a file from a folder, you can refer to the below process.

I tested it with one type of file which starts with “**U**”.

1. Create 2 variables, one to store **maxdate** and the other to store the **latestfilename**. Assign any initial value (which is the past date) in maxdate variable.

[image]

2. Using `Get Metadata` activity getting the list of files that starts with “**U**” by hardcoding the filename parameter value as “**U**”.

[image]

***Output of Get Metadata1***:

[image]

3. Pass the Get Metadata activity output **child items** to the `ForEach` activity to loop through all the files from the list.

[image]

4. Inside **ForEach**--> Use another `Get Metadata` activity to get the metadata (last modified date & filename) of the current file in the loop.

[image]

***Output of Get Metadata2:***

[image]

- Connect **Get Metadata** to `If Condition` and use **greater** function and [**ticks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#ticks) function to evaluate the If condition expression.
- Ticks function returns Integer value of specified timestamp and using greater function compare the 2 values.

  ```
    @greater(ticks(activity('Get_lastmodified_date_and_name').output.lastModified),ticks(formatDateTime(variables('maxdate'))))
  ```

[image]

6. When the expression evaluates to **true** add (2 set variable) activities to store the last modified date and respective file name into the variables created initially.

***Maxdate***:

[image]

***LatestFileName***:

[image]

> **Note**: These variable's values will be overridden if the next iteration file in the loop contains a timestamp greater than the previous (or first) loop file.

7. In the next activities, Use the variable filename (latestfilename) to assign the value for the filename parameter in the source.

[image]